# Handle Permission Denied Error in windows Python

Tags: python

i want to copy and paste a file into a directory
so i use shutil library in python

```
file_path = 'C:/Users/user/Downloads/Telegram Desktop/speech.py'
target_path = 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/'
shutil.copyfile(file_path,target_path)
```

then i got that error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\shutil.py", line 264, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/user/Desktop'
```

**how can i fix this?**

Comment: try running cmd as admin and then run this code, otherwise You may handle it using `try/except`, but then still You won't be able to do anything to the file, it just won't throw an error and stop Your code (also when using `try/except` either except the specific error or print out the exception to know what happened, DO NOT USE bare `except:` (suggestion))

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide the full path to the copy destination, not just to the destination directory

```
target_path = 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/speech.py'
```